# How to tell gazelle that a go file is meant for go_default_test and not go_default_library?

Tags: go, go-testing, bazel-gazelle, gazelle

I have a file, `embed_testdata.go`, meant to be used in tests but does not itself have tests (so I don't want to suffix it with `_test.go`). How do I tell `gazelle` that it's really test source and not prod source?

FYI, simply adding it to `go_default_test` and removing it from `go_default_library` doesn't work since `gazelle` undoes that manual edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#directives are all the valid `gazelle` directives.

There's no specific directive that tells it to treat a non-`_test.go` file as a test but there are two that can be used to that effect, `exclude` and `keep`:

```
# gazelle:exclude embed_testdata.go
…
go_test(
    name = "go_default_test",
    srcs = [
        "embed_testdata.go",  # keep
…
```

When embedding a file system, something like the following is also needed:

```
go_test(
    name = "go_default_test",
…
    embedsrcs = glob(["testdata/**"]), # keep
…
```